# Iterate Over CSV, Call API With Parameters

Tags: python, pandas, rest, loops, numpy

Whew! New Python learner here. Finally got a realistic project to undertake/learn.

**Goal**:

- **Using**: [The USGS Earthquake API](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/) and a Jupyter Notebook
- **Given**: An Event Table of Event ID, Datetime (in various formats and some missing values), Latitude and Longitude (some missing values)
- **Add**: Values from Event Table to API GET request
- **Return**: A table of earthquakes within given radius, correlated by Event ID

**Steps Taken:**

1. Interrogate Event Table and drop blank rows (Ref: [Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.04-missing-values.html#Dropping-null-values)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pandas.read_csv("tbLatLongDates.csv")
df.dropna()
print(df)
```

- Results
  [image]
- Question 1: Why didn't `df.dropna()` remove the `Nan` values from rows with `NaN` records?

  2. Convert and Concatenate `EVENT_DATE` and `EVENT_TIME` into ISO8601 standard input for API calls

     - NO IDEA how to do this!
  3. Iterate over cleaned up and converted data set to produce API calls

     - NO IDEA how to iterate over CSV file.
     - Here is the valid API call for a single request.
     - Question 2: How does one iterate / insert values dynamically into this using python?

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?"
payload = ""
querystring = {
    "format": "geojson",
    "starttime": datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1),
    "endtime": datetime.today(),
    "latitude": 47,
    "longitude": -122,
    "maxradiuskm": 300,
    "orderby": "magnitude-asc"
}

r = requests.get(url, params=querystring)

print(r)
data = r.json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

This responds with nice json output. From here I feel like I could get things dialed in. My big unknown is how to iterate over the CSV and dynamically add values to the API call.

Can anyone provide insights?
Thank you!

Comment: `df.dropna(inplace=True)` or `df = df.dropna()` [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: wow @furas, that was fast. That worked to remove `NaN`'s. Now how do I iterate over the CSV and add parameters to each API request? :)

Comment: in pandas you don't have to iterate it - you have `df.apply(function)` or `df.map(function)` to run function with all rows. [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)